# Get osm pedestrian network with osmnx and delete roads if a footway is along this road

Tags: python, osmnx

I am using osmnx to download the osm pedestrian network. I use this code to do so:

With trial and error, I found out that using a custom filter together with *network_type="walk"* gave most accurate results to me. So first I define my custom filter:

```
cf ='["highway"~"bridleway|corridor|elevator|footway|living_street|path|pedestrian|primary|primary_link|residential|secondary|secondary_link|service|steps|tertiary|tertiary_link|track|trunk|trunk_link|unclassified"]
```

Then I get the graph:

```
Point="Wipkingen, Kreis 10, Zürich, Bezirk Zürich, Zürich, Schweiz"
 G = ox.graph_from_place(Point, network_type='walk', buffer_dist=2000,truncate_by_edge=True,simplify=False,custom_filter=cf)
```

With this network, I do some shortest path searches. For my analysis, it is important on which side of the street people walking (it is a thermal comfort study). So what happens now, is that for some shortest paths people walk on the road instead of the existing sidewalk. I know, that sidewalk information in osm is bad (see screenshots, where red are sidewalks or paths, green are the roads & nodes are black). But at least for those streets where sidewalk information exists, I want to use this information.

So my question is if there is a possibility to delete roads from the network where sidewalks are existing in parallel?

[OSM_B/W_basemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfBAh.png)
[GoogleSatelite_basemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigSL.jpg)

Comment: What is your method to identify all the roads where sidewalks are existing in parallel?

Comment: I do not have a method to identify them yet. I thought that this is a basic problem one might have faced before and that there is already an approach to do so...

Comment: I can't think of an algorithm sufficient to determine if two edges are parallel for long enough and close enough to pair them up. Unless there's data tagging them as such, the question here seems to be what an algorithm for that purpose would look like and how it would work.

Comment: thank you very much. I think I will just increase walking time for roads in order that sidewalks are preferred. Thank you for your great package though!